# Php function ftp_connect() not working on azure app service

Tags: php, azure, ftp, azure-web-app-service

I tried using php function ftp_connect() is a script on azure app service and it doesn't work. it doesn't return true or false but stops working. doesn't even return error.

then i tried to access that ftp server with azure kudu console by following command

> ftp ftp.xxx.com

but it returned with **"Access is denied."**

i'm supposing that ftp is not enabled on app service and i need to enable that setting or it could be something else. Also i'm new to azure so i'm not familiar with its settings and stuff.

I just want to run the php code through which i'm able to connect to another server and perform some tasks through ftp. *Also i'm able to access the same server through code and cmd both from my local setup. its just something regarding azure i guess.*

Comment: Q: Did you enable SSL encryption ? (say SFTP)

Comment: is it required for FTP ?

Comment: i need to use it via FTP only not SFTP i guess.

Comment: What/how exactly does `ftp` return *"Access is denied"*? That looks like login failure, rather than connection failure. What would be different problem that you have with `ftp_connect`. + If the problem is indeed about enabling outgoing FTP on Azure, that you do not have a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). + @KenLee SFTP is not SSL. SFTP uses SSH. SSL (or actually TLS) is used with FTPS.

Comment: this can definitely fall in a programming question since i wrote a program that didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

So this took some while to detect that FTP was turned off on azure. i just checked if ftp is turned on for my server or not. simply used phpinfo() to check it. this took a lot of time since ftp_connect() doen't return any error in this case. **@php** should give something in return if this happens.

issue request for self reference: https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/9898